# How to implement ssh over XMPP, by C programming?

Tags: c, unix, xmpp, systems-programming, sus

I write xmpp bot in linux that invoke remote shell for me.
Any one could intoduce my which technologies should I know about them, to write this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to write a xmpp bot in linux, you need to use an XMPP library like libstrophe (http://strophe.im/libstrophe) for C language or any other language see XMPP clients in xmpp.org. As far as remote shell is concerned you can use [forkpty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/forkpty) system call to start a shell and communicate with it using its standard input and output file descriptors. A more symplistic approache could be to use the **exec** family of functions.